# Dictionary serialization: System.Exception: Type <Type> is not a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, json-serialization

I have a dictionary in my type, which I want to get as input on controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace LM.WebApp.Models.ApiModels;

[JsonDictionary]
public class Values
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> values { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public IList<string> labels { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Values values { get; set; }
}

public class DictionaryImportApiModel
{
    public IList<Data> data { get; set; }
}
```

I'm passing on input this test JSON:

```
{
  "data":
  [
    {
      "is_active": true,
      "labels": [
        "SYSTEM",
        "EXTERNAL"
      ],
      "name": "MEDICATION_REQUEST_INTENT",
      "values": {
        "order": "Замовлення ліків",
        "plan": "План застосування"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And getting error from question title and null dictionary in inbound object. I have changed `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and removed attribute `[JsonDictionary]` from `Values` class and added `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` just after `AddControllersWithViews` in `Startup`. Exception is gone, but dictionary in inbound object is still null. Is it necessary to use custom converters (like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524#issuecomment-524619972))
to handle dictionary?

Comment: Could you show the serializer code too?

Comment: Shouldn't you have one more level of nesting i.e. `values.values`?

Comment: And if you're using .Net-6.0 use `System.Text` not *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson*

Comment: Don't violate C# naming conventions for the sake of JSON ones; use JsonProperty attributes to declare what the JSON is called and then call your C# anything you like (for example IsActive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `values` type of `Data` model to `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
public class Data
{
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public IList<string> labels { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> values { get; set; }
}
```

One of the conventions supported by main .NET json serializers (both `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`, maybe some others, but have not worked with them) is converting json object to and from `Dictionary`, so you don't need extra wrapper class `Values`.

P.S.

Unless you have specific naming conventions in your project - there is no need to name classes properties the same way as they are named in the source json. For `Newtonsoft.Json` you can either mark properties with [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm) or trying to setup corresponding [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm) in serializer settings (`System.Text.Json` has similar options).